# SelectKBest sklearn varying computation times

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was trying to do feature selection on a synthetic multilabel dataset. It was observed that the computation time for giving the complete dataset to SelectKBest was much higher as compared to time required while giving one feature at a time. In this example below only one label (or target variable) is considered.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2, SelectKBest, f_classif

# Generate a multilabel dataset
x, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=40000, n_features = 1000, sparse = False, n_labels = 4, n_classes = 9,
  return_indicator = 'dense', allow_unlabeled = True, random_state = 1000)

X_df = pd.DataFrame(x)
y_df = pd.DataFrame(y)

%%time
selected_features2 = [] 
for label in y_df.columns.tolist()[0:1]:
    selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k='all')
    selected_features = [] 
    for ftr in X_df.columns.tolist():
        selector.fit(X_df[[ftr]], y_df[label])
        selected_features.extend(np.round(selector.scores_,4))
```

> CPU times: user 3.2 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 3.2 s . Wall time: 3.18 s

```
%%time
sel_features = []
for label in y_df.columns.tolist()[0:1]:
    selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k='all')
    selector.fit(X_df, y_df[label])
    sel_features.extend(np.round(selector.scores_,4))
```

> CPU times: user 208 ms, sys: 37.2 s, total: 37.4 s Wall time: 37.4 s

```
%%time
sel_features = []
for label in y_df.columns.tolist()[0:1]:
    selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k='all')
    selector.fit(X_df.as_matrix(), y_df[label].as_matrix())
    sel_features.extend(np.round(selector.scores_,4))
```

> CPU times: user 220 ms, sys: 35.4 s, total: 35.7 s Wall time: 35.6 s .

Why is there this much difference in the computation times?

Comment: What's the point of using `SelectKBest` on a dataset with only one feature?

Comment: @Stergios The number of features is 1000 here. The number of targets considered is one in the example above.

Comment: In the 1st example, `selector.fit(X_df[[ftr]], y_df[label])` selects only one feature, no?

Comment: @Stergios Okay. Yes here selector.fit is iterated for each feature and this is to find the F-score. Here both `sel_features` and `selected_features` are equal. Should not the `selector.fit(X_df, y_df[label]` be faster than iterating over each feature?

Comment: I see that the CPU times are much less in the last two cases. I'm not sure why the system time has increased that much.